Edge no funciona con Selenium
Tengo un pequeño problema y es que he desarrollado una herramienta a traves de selenium pero uno de los pc clientes no puede arrancarla ya que al lanzar no inicia edge con este codigo:
try:
    driver = webdriver.Edge()
    driver.get(url)
except Exception as e:
    print(error_edge) 
    print (e)

Por politica de la propia empresa he de usar Edge asi que no puedo cambiar a otro navegador, ademas el error que me da es que Selenium es incapaz de encontrar el driver, he revisado ya el path en las variables de la cuenta, esta bien enrutado. y he probado a añadir un Edge_service directamente al driver pero al abrir la ventana de Edge el script ya no puede interactuar con el. Alguien sabe que puede ser ? Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

¿Estás siguiendo la documentación?

Cual es la relación entre el titulo y la pregunta? La pregunta no menciona ninguna "prueba automatizada"

Buenas, intenta poner dentro de webdriver.Edge(executable_path="C:\ruta_de_msedgedriver.exe").
msedgedriver.exe es el ejecutable de edge, a ver si especificandolo directamente puedes solucionarlo.
Sino, para tener mas informacion del problema selenium cuenta con un modulo de errores que se llama WebDriverException, lo pones como otro except aparte del que tienes ya y te muestra el error especifico. Lo tienes en selenium.common.exceptions como WebDriverException
